# Mention user in post to page from app using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I need to mention user in post to page from our app. We are sharing post to users wall with users permission and we can post same thing to our fanpage. But now we want to mention same username in our fanpage post.

My code :

```
    $page_info = $GLOBALS["facebook"]->api("/page_id?fields=access_token");

        if (!empty($page_info['access_token'])) {
            $args = array(
                    'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
                    'message' => '@[{userid}:1:{name}] message',
//              name : 'sdfg',
                'link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/jedwsefdtlc/app_id?ref=ts',
//              description : 'To vote https://facebook.com/page/app_id',
//              actions:{
//                  name : "Vote now",
//                  link: "https://www.facebook.com/page/app_id?ref=ts"
//              },
//              url:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Ara_ararauna_Luc_Viatour.jpg',
//              link:{
                'picture' => "https://example.com/app_dev.php/../bundles/soweb/images/chefs/chef_img/100_chef.jpg",//,
                    'name'=> "AFDS",
                    'caption'=>"caption",
                    'description' =>"description"
            );
```

I referred  [this](http://digitizor.com/2011/01/24/tag-user-facebook-graph/) link

But in post text displayed as it is. It is not tagging. Any help?

Comment: If we ask user permission something like that?

Comment: the method described in this link is old, and doesn't work anymore. With version 2 of the graph API, it's possible to [tag users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends) but I can't figure out if this works for pages.